# Use data from excel sheet to replace values in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple excel file with product names. First row is the category (A1: Water, A2: Sparkling, A3:Still, B1: Soft Drinks, B2: Coca Cola, B3: Orange Juice, B4:Lemonade etc.), each cell below is a different product. I would like to replace the cells of another dataframe (df1) with the product categories. For example, Coca Cola would become Soft Drinks. If the product is not in the excel it would not be replaced (ex. Cookie).

[image: A1: Water, A2: Sparkling, A3:Still, B1: Soft Drinks, B2: Coca Cola, B3: Orange Juice, B4:Lemonade etc.]

print(df1)

```
         Product  Quantity
0      Coca Cola  1234
1      Cookie     4
2      Still      333
3      Chips     88
```

Outcome:

```
print (df1)

       Product      Quantity
0      Soft Drinks   1234
1      Cookie        4
2      Water         333
3      Snacks        88
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a lookup dictionary from the Excel data frame and use it to replace the product names with the categories (products not found in the dictionary are left unreplaced as requested):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\temp\product_names.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Product': ['Coca Cola','Cookie','Still','Chips'], 'Quantity': [1234,4,333,88]})

lu = df.unstack().dropna().reset_index()
df1.Product.replace(dict(zip(lu.iloc[:,2],lu.iloc[:,0])),inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
       Product  Quantity
0  Soft Drinks      1234
1       Cookie         4
2        Water       333
3       Snacks        88
```

PS: This is the csv file to paste into your Excel sheet at A1 to reproduce the example:

```
Water,Soft Drinks,Sandwich,Snacks
Sparkling,Coca Cola,Ham and cheese,Chips
Still,Orange Juice,Vegetarian,
,Lemonade,Club,
,,Spinach,
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The goal was to use the easy to navigate Excel sheet that I showed in the question. The CSV file you show is not easily modifiable. Is there a way to transform the excel sheet (see picture above) into a dictionary?

Comment: The csv file is only attached to reproduce the example, as I couldn't attach the Excel file here. Line 1 of the code reads the Excel file - you will have to adapt the path and file name of course. The data for the replacement dictionary is read from this Excel file into the dataframe `df`.

Comment: @Huebschi Did you manage to get it running? If so and it solved your problem, you should consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).